# AngularJS - issue when embedding the Youtube video url from directive to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, youtube, angularjs-directive

Here is working code [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ei2RdftdSepCrPjeEIC9?p=preview)  in the controller

```
public JsonResult videohome()
        {
            BaseController bc = new BaseController();
            var video = (from n in bc.db.Video where n.Video == true select n).FirstOrDefault();
            var videos = new Videohome { youtubeid = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + video.youtubeid };
            return Json(videos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public class Videohome
        {
            public string youtubeid { get; set; }
        }
```

It gives the ouptput as **{"youtubeid":"//www.youtube.com/embed/_kux-YQujjM"}**

But when i load this output into my script it displays error,

```
<script>

        countryApp.controller('Homevideo', ['$scope', "$http",'$sce', function (scope, sce, http) {
            http.get('@Url.Content("/sample/videohome")').success(function (data) {
                $scope.video = data;
                $scope.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.video + $scope.video.youtubeid);
             });
         }]);
</script>
        <div ng-controller="Homevideo" > <br />         
         <iframe width="100%" height="250" ng-src="{{videoUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            <p>{{videoUrl}}</p>       
          </div>
```

Did i missed anything in my code, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you sure what you attached angular.js to your app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working version (without the http): http://plnkr.co/edit/6M0qdSNlUe1f7mhT7ASt?p=preview
I spotted few errors, first, try to organize the import in the same order and with a '$' prefix :

```
countryApp.controller('Homevideo', ['$scope', "$http",'$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce)
```

The second thing I noticed is `$scope.video + $scope.video.youtubeid` I think you're not doing it right and `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.video.youtubeid);` should be enough as $scope.video is an json array it has nothing to do with the url.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks This code helps for my issue... :)